# Parse deletes objects inside array when updating

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, parse-platform

I have a like feature on my app and when the user double taps, it adds there user name to an array on Parse. However, anytime another user double taps, it appends the array, but deletes the other user that was already there. This is my code!

```
var userLikes = [PFUser.current()]

func doubleTapped(){
    postedImage.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {

        self.postedImage.alpha = 1

    })
  let likesQuery = PFQuery(className: "FeatherPosts")
    likesQuery.getObjectInBackground(withId: objectIdLabel.text!) { (object, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print ("error")
        }else{
            if let userLikes = object {
                userLikes["UserLikes"] = [self.userLikes]
                self.userLikes.append(PFUser.current().self)
                userLikes.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in
                    if success {
                        print("liked")
                    }else{
                        print("error")
                    }
                })
            }

        }
    }
 }
```

Please help. I'm still learning Parse so please be kind. Haha

Comment: I think, that `User` should have an array of some `ids` of "liked" objects, it would fix problem and it is the right way to do.

Comment: Took your advice. Haha. It worked.